# NSString is null but code does not recognize as null

Tags: objective-c

I have this app where I am populating an NSDictionary and then doing computations on the dictionary.

```
            tmp = nil;
            tmp = [singleEvent objectForKey:@"start_date"];

            if(tmp == nil)
            {
                startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1800/1/1 12:00:00"];
            }
            else
            {
                startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tmp];
            }
```

tmp is an NSString object, and singleEvent is an NSDictionary. Both are declared elsewhere. I did not include that part of the code for simplicity.

The key "start_date" of the dictionary will sometimes contain a date in string format, and sometimes it will be null.

I have handled the condition where it will be null, but the code never hits that line. I found out by debugging that even when tmp is null the executions goes to else part.

**In debug mode I get this when watching tmp:**

tmp = (NSNull *)

**But still else block is hit.**
So I am always getting a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSNull` is different to `nil`. `NSNull` (or, more explicitly, `[NSNull null]`) is a singleton used to represent the concept of "nil" that can be used in the Foundation collection classes. Because it's a singleton, you don't have to use `-isEqual:`, you can compare it directly.

To check for `NSNull`, you can do this:

```
if (tmp == [NSNull null])
```

Answer (score 2):

> The key "start_date" of the dictionary will sometimes contain a date in string format, and sometimes **it will be null**.

There's three cases:

1. The key `start_date` is not in your dictionary : the return value of `objectForKey:` will be `nil` (first condition is true);
2. The key `start_date` is in your dictionary and the value associated is `[NSNull null]` (of type `(NSNull *)` : the return value of `objectForKey:` will be `[NSNull null]` (second condition is true);
3. The key `start_date` is in your dictionary and the value associated is something else : the return value of `objectForKey:` will be the stored object (second condition is true);

But #2 and #3 really are the same: `NSNull` is an object like every other.

Do not confuse a null pointer (`nil`) and the Null object (`[NSNull null]`). To test the first, you have to do:

```
if (!tmp)
// or
if (tmp == nil)
```

and for the second:

```
if (tmp == [NSNull null])
```

Answer (score 1):

NSNull is a different thing than nil. Perhaps this will work:

```
if ( [[NSNull null] isEqual:tmp] ) {
```

Comment: why `isEqual:` , you could have used `==`

Comment: You're right that == would have worked since [NSNull null] is guaranteed to be a singleton. But I think this style removes any doubt about the correctness of the code; anyone reading this code wouldn't have to remember or look up in the docs whether the singleton-ness of [NSNull null] is guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

How about making it a bit smaller like that ? also I think your problem was you're using objectForKey not valueForKey, valueForKey will return Nil.

```
startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1800/1/1 12:00:00"];

if([singleEvent valueForKey:@"start_date"])
        startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[singleEvent valueForKey:@"start_date"]];

NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
```